# How to manage node.js forever logs on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, logging, node.js

I have a Node.js application running on AWS EC2 ubuntu server in which I use 'forever' module to keep the app running. I also utilize the logging done by forever (which it dumps to a file in the .forever folder). With time my log file is growing large and difficult to manage. I also have some apps on Heroku where I use the amazing service PaperTrail to manage logs and alerts. My question is, is there any service on AWS that I can use to manage my logs and error alerts, like PaperTrail on Heroku? Also, how would I be able to attach my application or the log file to this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. Rotate your logs using [LogRotate](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-rotate-log-files/).
2. Use [CloudWatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) for log file storage. After they're in CWL you can delete from your server.

To help with error alerts you'd need to edit your question to provide more information. [AWS Simple Notification Service](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) may be applicable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I actually did come across CloudWatch logs a few hours ago had been setting it up. Faced a new problem now, CWL can't read the log file because it doesn't have timestamps. Forever isn't putting timestamps in the logs. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I can't help with Forever sorry, never heard of it. If a system isn't putting timestamps on logs it's not really sounding like a good log system.